# computing a sum, over the natural numbers of the form $p^q$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Arrange in magnitude all natural numbers of the form $p^q$ ($p, q$ positive integers $\ge 2$) and denote the $n$-th of the numbers so arranged by $p_n$, so that $$(p_1, p_2, \ldots) = (4, 8, 9, 16, 25, 27, 32, \ldots)$$
We then have $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{p_n-1} = 1$$

I thought that one can show this by the squeeze theorem.

Is the following correct? Is it ok to show that $$S \le \sum_{p = 2}^{\infty}\sum_{q = 2}^{\infty}\left(\frac1{p^q-1}-\frac1{(p^2)^q-1}-\frac1{(p^3)^q-1}-\frac1{(p^4)^q-1}\right)\le \sum_{p = 2}^{\infty}\sum_{q = 2}^{\infty}\frac1{p^q} = 1$$

Setting $x = p^q$ in Wolfram, the second inequality holds for every $x > 1$, which is our case. If I use less negative terms in the first inequality I'm not able to upper bound the general term by $1/p^q$. I'm not completely sure of the first inequality. Is it correct? I'm removing terms which occurs more than one time; for instance $\frac1{15}$ get counted twice, since $=\frac1{2^4-1} = \frac1{4^2-1}$. How about the lower bound?

Comment: This is known as the [Goldbach-Euler Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldbach%E2%80%93Euler_theorem).  Goldbach's argument, provided in that link, is helpful, I think,  though, as it manipulates divergent series, it isn't rigorous.

Comment: Note:  you should indicate that duplicates are avoided.  Thus the perfect power $16$ arises only once, though it is both $2^4$ and $4^2$.

Comment: Hi @lulu! I didn't know it was a theorem. What do you think about my proof?

Comment: I am not following your argument.  If you only sum over cases where $p$ is prime your sum should be strictly lower than the desired case (as terms are omitted from a positive series).   A simple argument (and a discussion of the various non-rigorous arguments) appears [here](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/bibiloni206.pdf).

Comment: Why strictly lower? For example I'm not counting powers where $p = 6$

Comment: Thanks for the reference though!

Comment: Right, your sum deletes  terms from the original, so it is strictly smaller.  Or perhaps I am misreading.

Comment: Let me know if it looks good, in case you want to read it all! XD

Comment: In particular, the telescoping series $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac 1{n(n-1)}=1$ but you appear to claim that you still get $1$ even if you only sum over prime $n$.  I see the prime sum as less than $.8$

Comment: You are definitely right. It's not even a telescoping series :( what a huge mistake. By the way I removed that part, hoping at least that the upper bound is ok.